# Does OpenstackSDK have support for usage metrics?

Tags: openstack, telemetry, ceilometer, openstacksdk

So...I'm facing a problem which I need the available amount of resources (and how are they being used) in the DCs (focusing on each project/server/network consume) of my Openstack (Stein) through python code (cause the other functionalities are in python and I don't like mixing languages if it have support for a functionality).

Are there any support for this on OpenstackSDK libraries? If yes, where to find the API documentation (or code examples of usage). If don't, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use existing Nova APIs to list down Compute capabilities and available resources.

> nova hypervisor-stats

```
+----------------------+-------+
| Property             | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| count                | 2     |
| current_workload     | 0     |
| disk_available_least | 1378  |
| free_disk_gb         | 1606  |
| free_ram_mb          | 47003 |
| local_gb             | 1606  |
| local_gb_used        | 0     |
| memory_mb            | 48027 |
| memory_mb_used       | 1024  |
| running_vms          | 0     |
| vcpus                | 28    |
| vcpus_used           | 0     |
+----------------------+-------+
```

You can automate it by wrapping it in shell or calling python-openstack lib.

Comment: I did it...but I don't want to now hypervisor stats. My problem is focused on servers and networks.